# Argument Error in Python

Tags: python

So I have the line of code in python that I keep getting an error on.
Line of code:

```
input("This is your", movecounter, "move, type the number you want to move north")
```

Line 1 was just `import random`

Error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in berries
TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3
```

How do I fix this? I don't see any args???

Comment: Please up vote the correct answers and select your winning answer from the below 4. All are right and offer you info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the *least*, you want to replace the commas with pluses and call `str` on `movecounter` (which I'm guessing is an integer).

```
input("This is your " + str(movecounter) + 
    " move, type the number you want to move north")
```

Arguments are separated by commas, so you were in fact giving `input` three arguments.

A more pythonic way of doing it is using  [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings):

```
input("This is your {0:d} move, type the number you want to move north".format(
    movecounter))
```

You could also use the old-style [`%` formatting operator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) as suggested by Kimvais, but I recommend learning and using `str.format`. It was made to supersede and improve upon the old `%` operator, which will eventually be deprecated. Many still use it though.

Comment: Using `+` rather than some form of templating to build strings is fragile and non-idiomatic, so there's really not tons of reasons to show it. (By the way, the backslash in that snippet wasn't necessary.) 

Also, I don't know that there are plans ever to deprecate `%` string formatting—if there were, why wait?

Comment: @Mike I show it for completeness; I wanted to illustrate how OP could make it work while still using the "method" he attempted to use. I've edited the answer to emphasise that it's not a good solution. As for the deprecation of `%`, let me quote [what's new in python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html): "*The plan is [...] to start deprecating the % operator in Python 3.1.*". The waiting is because, as I pointed out, *many still use it*.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The idea of "will deprecate in the future" still seems really odd to me, as deprecation doesn't actually *do* anything. As soon as you realize the plan is eventually to remove something, it seems like it should be deprecated immediately. Cranking up the warning level on Python 3.2 and the dev version of 3.3, it looks like `str.__mod__` hasn't started emitting deprecation warnings yet.

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is `input("This is your %d move, type the number you wat to move north" % movecounter)`

Using `,` to concatenate strings only works for `print`, so it's better to avoid it - even in print.

Answer (score 0):

Comma is used to sperate arguments to the function input() you've therefore given input three arguments. If you want to create a single string you can't use comma.

```
input_string = "This is your" + movecounter + "move, type the number you want to move north"
input(input_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

the error said wrong args inside `input()` function. `input()` can have 0 or 1 arg, you feed them 3 args.

to fix this, feed 1 arg to `input()`. and the more proper way for python3 onward is to use `format()`:

```
input("This is your {} move, type the number you want to move north".format(movecounter))
```